# Does Qpid Broker 7 support ${variable} substitution in its config file?

Tags: qpid

I am upgrading from version 6 to version 7, which means switching from from instantiating a `Broker` to using the `SystemLauncher`.

In particular, I had specified the keystore with a variable, and am now providing that via the `systemConfigAttributes` to start. But it reports that it can't find they keystore, and names my `${variable}` as the keystore, rather than the value I provided.

I've also tried using one of the standard variables `${qpid.amqp_port}` instead, just in case, and it's still reporting that variable name rather than a value.

Is this a feature that doesn't work any more, or am I plugging it in wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is still used in the broker configuration, and so you should be able to use it.  Can you share your code / config so we can see what the problem might be?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't easily extract the code. But it's very helpful just to know that I'm not barking up the wrong tree. Thanks.